# How to properly close a query so it doesn't intercept with other queries?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my template part I am using a function which looks like this:

```
function job_listings($id = null) {
$output = '';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job-listings',
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post();

    if($id == get_the_id()) {
        $output .= '<option selected value="'.get_the_ID().'">'.get_the_title().'</option>';
    } else {
        $output .= '<option value="'.get_the_ID().'">'.get_the_title().'</option>';
    }

}

wp_reset_postdata();

return $output;
```

}

...and I have struggled to realize what was the problem but I see now that every time I try to use `the_ID()` or `get_the_ID()` after the function above the ID prints ID from the particular function which I don't get because I thought the `wp_reset_postdata()` is closing the query.

For example:

```
<form id="job-apply-<?php the_ID(); ?>" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="full-name">Full Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="full-name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sel1">Select Position:</label>
                <select class="form-control form-control-lg" id="job-position">
                    <?php job_listings(get_the_ID()); ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Upload Resume</label>
                <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonText="Select a File" id="resume-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">Additional Comments:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Apply</button>
        </form>
```

in the id of the `form` `id="job-apply-<?php the_ID(); ?>"` prints the current post's ID like it should, but after the use of the function `job_listings()` in the id of the `input` `id="resume-<?php the_ID(); ?>"` prints the last ID in the above mentioned function's query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change ID in your if statement. Change the get_the_id() to $loop->ID use the ID inside the $loop.

```
if($id == $loop->ID) {
    $output .= '<option selected value="'.$loop->ID.'">'.get_the_title($loop->ID).'</option>';
} else {
    $output .= '<option value="'.$loop->ID.'">'.get_the_title($loop->ID).'</option>';
}
```